# MySQL index on datetime not being used with nested query

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing

I'm trying to speed up a slow report query that takes a list of dates from an inner query and uses subqueries in the outer query to aggregate various data based on each date (example below).

These subquery tables have DATETIME columns, so I used a BETWEEN to avoid having to use a DATE() call, which would disallow any index from being used.

However, indexes on those DATETIME fields seem to be ignored if the inner query returns multiple dates.

**MySQL Version: 5.6.16**

**To recreate (simplified):**

-- Create a table with a datetime column

`CREATE TABLE testtable (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  createddate DATETIME NULL,
  value INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));`

-- Add an index to the datetime

`ALTER TABLE testtable 
ADD INDEX dateIndex (createddate ASC);`

-- insert some data

`insert into testtable(createddate,value)
values ('2014-08-08 12:45:56',5),('2014-08-09 10:22:12',32),('2014-08-09 06:36:31',465);`

-- **Where it goes wrong: sum the value based on a date from an inner query (multiple dates)**

`explain
select 
   (select sum(value) 
   from testtable 
   where createddate between temp.tdate and date_add(temp.tdate,interval 1 day)) as value from
(select '2014-08-08' as tdate union select '2014-08-09' as tdate) temp;`

-- EXPLAIN result (for the relevant table only)

-- # id, select_type,          table,       type,  possible_keys, key,  key_len, ref,  rows, Extra
-- '2',  'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'testtable', 'ALL', **'dateIndex',   NULL**, NULL,    NULL, '3',  '**Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2)**'

It can see the index but does not use it; it needs to check a range, but I have to use the BETWEEN because I am comparing a DATETIME to a date (using *WHERE DATE(createddate) = temp.tdate* will not allow the index to be used)

-- But the index is used IF I only have one row in the inner query/table

`explain 
select 
   (select sum(value) 
   from testtable 
   where createddate between temp.tdate and date_add(temp.tdate,interval 1 day)) as value 
from (select '2014-08-08' as tdate) temp;`

-- EXPLAIN result
-- # id,  select_type,          table,       type,    possible_keys, key,         key_len, ref,  rows, Extra
--   '2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'testtable', 'range', '**dateIndex**',   '**dateIndex**', '6',     NULL, '1',   **'Using index condition'**

My current solution option is to split the DATETIME into separate DATE and TIME columns so that I can use `WHERE createddate = temp.tdate` instead of the BETWEEN: in this case the index is used fine but it would require a lot of other changes in the main code.

I'm familiar with basic index usage but this one has my little brain befuddled. Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use a single date range and group by DATE(createdate), instead?

Comment: Hi @antlersoft, I think you mean get rid of the inner query and use a BETWEEN and GROUP BY? my 'real' query has multiple subqueries like the one above that returns 'value', while the inner query that returns dates also has some complexity (various financial values are calculated for certain dates based on customer activity within a range!). My hope is to understand why the index is not being used in the scenario given and if it ever can be; I am also looking at restructuring it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the query optimizer is willing to do an indexed range query once, but rather than doing the indexed range query multiple times it believes it is more efficient to make a full pass through the indexed table once and check each row against the full set of date ranges--

This is a common heuristic for query optimizers, basically because the optimizer can't tell that each date range from the sub-query supply isn't going to give back most or all of the data in the indexed table.

Sometimes you can make the optimizer be smarter about this by making sure your table statistics are up to date, but sometimes the optimizer won't be swayed.

You might see if you can restructure the query to make it more optimizer-friendly, perhaps by:

- specifying a single date range and then grouping by each individual day within the range.
- repeat the whole query for each single sub-range and take the union of the results